# How to derive this Kubo formula expressed with Green functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, greens-functions

Kubo formula $\sigma_{ab}(\textbf{q},\omega)=\frac{1}{\omega} (\pi_{ab}(\textbf{q},\omega) - \pi_{ab}(\textbf{q},0))$ is usually given in terms of the current-current correlation function
$$\pi_{ab}(\textbf{q},\omega)=\int_0^\infty dt e^{i\omega t}\langle[\hat{J}_a^\dagger(\textbf{q},t),\hat{J}_b(\textbf{q},0)]\rangle.$$
Sometimes I see another form
$$\pi_{ab}(\textbf{q},\omega)=\frac{ie^2}{\beta}\sum_{\textbf{k},\omega_n}\mathrm{tr}\left[\hat{\textbf{v}}_a(\textbf{k}+\frac{\textbf{q}}{2}) G_0(\textbf{k},\omega_n)\hat{\textbf{v}}_b(\textbf{k}+\frac{\textbf{q}}{2}) G_0(\textbf{k}+\textbf{q},\omega_n+\nu_m)\right]\bigg\rvert_{\nu_m\rightarrow\omega+i0^+}$$
where $\hat{\textbf{v}}=\partial_\textbf{k}h_\textbf{k}$ is the velocity operator of the Hamiltonian $h_\textbf{k}$ and $G_0$ is the (single-particle) Green's function. E.g., its $\textbf{q}=0$ version is given as Eq. (3) in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.78.195424) and as Eq. (6) in [this one](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.157001). My question is how to derive this formula and optionally to what extent it holds (only for quadratic Hamiltonian or even beyond).

Comment: what do you mean by velocty operator

Comment: @physshyp updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

partial answer: $\pi$ is the vacuum polarization tensor  since its kubo you want only one loop calculation

assume we have feynman rules

[image: llklk]
let this$=e\hat{\mathbb{v}}_a$

[image: kr image description here]
now let this $=G_{ab}$
finally the vacuum polarization tensor is
[image: o]

now assume periodic imaginary time we have

$$\pi_{ab}(\textbf{q},\omega)=\frac{ie^2}{\beta}\sum_{\textbf{k},\omega_n}\mathrm{tr}\left[\hat{\textbf{v}}_a(\textbf{k}+\frac{\textbf{q}}{2}) G_0(\textbf{k},\omega_n)\hat{\textbf{v}}_b(\textbf{k}+\frac{\textbf{q}}{2}) G_0(\textbf{k}+\textbf{q},\omega_n+\nu_m)\right]\bigg\rvert_{\nu_m\rightarrow\omega+i0^+}$$
the mistake you make is you do not include hamiltonian to your question but its important,  hamiltonian has basically an interaction term $$eAc^\dagger c v$$ that's why we have that vertex rule than we write the partition function taylor expand that interaction term you get this.

$\frac{i}{\beta}$ comes from the fact that its one loop. Trace comes from contraction.

Comment: idea here is $\pi$ is cur cur correlation func. thus write you partition func taylor expand int int. term take double derivative of wrt to $A$ you get cur cur corr that is the diagram I show

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking the [Mahan's book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780306463389) - the notation seems resembling his derivation.

Generally, when the Kubo formula is written in terms of one-particle Green's functions, it means that we are either dealing with a non-interacting case or one of the vertices has been *"dressed"* by the interactions. Non-interacting case in this context is much more ubiquitous than it may seem at first - it figure extensively in all kinds of impurity-related problems (where an averaging over the impurities enters at a later stage).